# Back to RootViewController when in stack more then 10 controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've a lot of controllers, two controllers have a back button which `popToViewController`. When i transition from one controller to another over and over again and than tap a back button, i can move between them a long time. I did't now how make it fine. I try this: if controllers in stack more than 7 - `popToRootViewController`, else `popToViewController`.

```
int controllersQuantity = 7;
if ((int)self.navigationController.viewControllers > controllersQuantity) {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
} else {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This does't work. Help to resolve my task, thx for answers.

Comment: Had the same problem. I did it like: - (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
works great in my case.

Comment: i don't need dismiss, i need pop

Comment: - (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender { [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; } it will not work if you not use presentViewController.......try to use array..and move with index....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you casting a `NSArray` to `int` in this line: `(int)self.navigationController.viewControllers`?

The property is an array not an integer:

```
NSInteger controllersQuantity = 7;
if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers count] > controllersQuantity) {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
} else {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, i forgot about ..count... This works, thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

When your going like A → B → C → ... and want to get back to A from the further controllers, you can use this to to reach to the Root Controller.

```
-(IBAction)unwindToRootController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
```

Declare this action in your header(.h) file and then just connect your Button with the Exit Responder and select this event. It will pop you up to the root View Controller.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are assuming that storyboards are used, but it does not stated that anywhere.

Comment: this help), but not what i need)